# Find all coins available for Futures trading from binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I want to get a list of all the coins available for futures trading for Binance.  Originally I found a website and just put the coins in an array, but then I came accross this function:

`exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()`

So one element in this array looks like this:

```
    {
        'symbol': 'ETHBTC',
        'status': 'TRADING',
        'baseAsset': 'ETH',
        'baseAssetPrecision': 8,
        'quoteAsset': 'BTC',
        'quotePrecision': 8,
        'quoteAssetPrecision': 8,
        'baseCommissionPrecision': 8,
        'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8,
        'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'],
        'icebergAllowed': True,
        'ocoAllowed': True,
        'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True,
        'isSpotTradingAllowed': True,
        'isMarginTradingAllowed': True,
        'filters': [{
            'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER',
            'minPrice': '0.00000100',
            'maxPrice': '922327.00000000',
            'tickSize': '0.00000100'
        }, {
            'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE',
            'multiplierUp': '5',
            'multiplierDown': '0.2',
            'avgPriceMins': 5
        }, {
            'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE',
            'minQty': '0.00010000',
            'maxQty': '100000.00000000',
            'stepSize': '0.00010000'
        }, {
            'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL',
            'minNotional': '0.00010000',
            'applyToMarket': True,
            'avgPriceMins': 5
        }, {
            'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS',
            'limit': 10
        }, {
            'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE',
            'minQty': '0.00000000',
            'maxQty': '913.13969153',
            'stepSize': '0.00000000'
        }, {
            'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS',
            'maxNumOrders': 200
        }, {
            'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS',
            'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5
        }],
 'permissions': ['SPOT', 'MARGIN']
}
```

And I thought well, surely the permissions will tell me whether its a FUTURES coin or not.  But looping through the all 1885 coins the vales in permissions are either SPOT, MARGIN, LEVERAGED.  And when I filter for each of these, not all of the coins listed are available in Binance Futures.

LEVERAGED would have been my best bet, but this only returns 40 coinpairs - where are a lot more than that available in Binance Futures. What is the criteria to search for here?

Is there a dynamic way to get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a list of all the coins available for futures trading for Binance by using api below:

```
futures_exchange_info = client.futures_exchange_info()  # request info on all futures symbols
trading_pairs = [info['symbol'] for info in futures_exchange_info['symbols']]
```

Comment: Dammit, I should have checked for a different function.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Do we have any REST api for the same?